# Merging Two Sorted Lists in Python In Linear Time

Tags: python, mergesort

I am trying to implement a merge of two sorted lists of integers in Python using only the basic list abstract data type operations. That is, I do not want to use `sorted()` which comes with Python.

Could someone tell me if this code is alright? Also, am I correct to understand that it is linear to the core? That is, it uses no Python operation that is non-linear in time?

```
 def mergeSortedLists(list1, list2):
     list3 = []
     while list1 and list2:
         if list1[len(list1) - 1] > list2[len(list2) - 1]:
             list3.append(list1.pop())
         else:
             list3.append(list2.pop())
     return list3 + list1 + list2
```

Answer (score 7):

**Correctness**

First of all, your *merging code is not correct*. If you have `list1 = [1, 2, 3]` and `list2 = [4, 5, 6]`, the result would be `[6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3]`.

Assuming, you are up to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, you should be comparing the first elements of the lists. The problem with that is that "pop" from the left is an expensive operation for a regular Python list. Switching to the [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) double-ended queue would solve it - `popleft()` is `O(1)`.

Fixed version:

```
from collections import deque


def merge_sorted_lists(left, right):
    """
    Merge sort merging function.
    TODO: Improve, add examples."""
    result = deque()

    left = deque(left)
    right = deque(right)

    while left and right:
        if left[0] > right[0]:
            result.append(right.popleft())
        else:
            result.append(left.popleft())
    return result + left + right
```

**Time Complexity Analysis (for your "incorrect" version)**

You are operating Python lists, according to the [Time Complexity page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity):

- the "get length" operation is `O(1)` (even though you can use `-1` in place of `len(list1) - 1` and `len(list2) - 1`)
- the "pop from the right" operation is `O(1)`
- the "append to the right" operation is `O(1)`

Which leads to overall complexity as `O(N + M)` where `N` is the length of the `list1` and `M` - the length of the list `list2`.

**Stylistic issues:**

- as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guide, use 4 spaces for indentation
- the function name should be `merge_sorted_lists` according to PEP8 variable naming guidelines
- `list1` should be better called `left`, `list2` - `right`, `list3`  - `result` for clarity purposes
- *missing docstring* explaining what function does

Comment: Am I correct to think that `pop()` is O(1) and `pop(1)` is O(n)?

Comment: Also, are we not assuming that the two list parameters have the same direction of sort (ascending or descending)? In your counter example you pick different directions.

Comment: @MadPhysicist exactly, popping from the left side of a list would require the list to be reallocated.

Comment: @MadPhysicist ah, my bad - that was a typo - the lists are `[1, 2, 3]` and `[4, 5, 6]`, same direction, sorry.

Comment: I implemented the code using only lists. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working implementation of the merge using only lists which (I think) functions linearly in time.

```
def mergeLists(a,b, direction):
         c = []
         # assuming ascending sortedness
         if direction == True:
             while a and b:
                 if a[len(a)-1] > b[len(b)-1]:
                     c.append(a.pop())
                 else:
                     c.append(b.pop())
             return (c + a[::-1] + b[::-1])[::-1]
         #assuming descending sortedness
         else:
             while a and b:
                 if a[len(a)-1] < b[len(b)-1]:
                      c.append(a.pop())
                 else:
                      c.append(b.pop())
             return (c+a[::-1]+b[::-1])[::-1]
```